# Toilet shutoff type identification

Tags: plumbing, toilet, valve

The valve won't turn so I'm looking to replace it.

I think it's a sweat type but I'm looking for confirmation.

Is this a sweat or threaded valve?

[image]

[image]

Edit: Scraped pipe
[image]

Edit 2:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a sweated valve with a screw on attachment for the toilet connection.

Rather than try to remove it, I'd buy a second one; they are typically quite cheap. With a helper available, use a giant wrench to try and break the valve free.  If the valve breaks, turn off the water; if it moves, great.

If it doesn't break free, take the handle off and then take the packing / valve mechanism out by unscrewing the front hex net and removing the valve innards.   Replace them with the parts from the donor valve.

If you get lucky, you'll save the time necessary to desolder, clean, and re-solder a valve.

Comment: If you think there's a possibility of breaking the pipe or valve, I'd suggest turning the water off upstream of this valve, first. At least that way, you'll only drain a pipe's worth of water on the bathroom floor instead of having city pressure pumping the water out while you're scrambling for the next valve.

Comment: That's what the helper is for :)    Also worth flushing the toilet and wiring the float so the valve stays closed for the duration of the repair.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a sweat or threaded valve?

It is difficult to determine if the pipe is galvanized or copper that has been painted silver.

Threaded for the former, sweated for the latter.

I bet on sweated copper  as i see a drop of what looks like solder just under the valve on the pipe. Plus i do not see any threads under the valve as you would typically see with galvanized and threaded connections.

Scrape the pipe to see if you can see copper.

Comment: Added a new picture. Looks like copper underneath

Comment: @EncryptedWatermelon  Yes, if you sand it with  some Emory cloth or low grit sandpaper  you can get a better assessment.

Comment: I went to the basement and got some Emory cloth. I was lazy before. Edit 2 in OP